# Data from multiple SQl Server Instances to a Central SQL Server for reporting purposes

Tags: sql, ssis, replication, instances

I have multiple (more then 20 locations having 10 Million Transactions/Year) locations with SQL server instances.

I need to move all these transactions (having independent identity on each site) from multiple sites to a Main SQL Instance in head office for reporting purpose only. I need solutions without using Bigint in Identity column and replication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using NEWID() or NEWSEQUENTIALID()

Comment: thanks for stopping by .But unique identifier (16bytes) will effect storage like bigint (8 bytes).

Comment: when you say there are huge number of records then dont you think you need such datatypes to store the huge number

Comment: I guess you have to either use bigint or newid() and there is no other option in sql server as far as I know.